# Add new items and slice from the top Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list with items like:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...];
```

I want, for every scroll, to add 15th new items and then to slice from the top another 15th elements.
Can you help me? Thanks!!!

Updated:

```
getMoreItems(items: any) {
        var lastIndex: number;
        if (items.visible.length) {
            var lastItem: any = _.last(items.visible);
            lastIndex = _.findLastIndex(items.allValues, { Name: lastItem.Name });
        }
        var startIndex = lastIndex + 1 || 0;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + 15, items.allValues.length);
        var newItems = items.allValues.slice(startIndex, endIndex);


        if (items.visible.length > 30) {
            items.visible = items.visible.slice(0, 15).concat(newItems);
        } else {
            items.visible = items.visible.concat(newItems);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to add 15 elements at the end and remove first 15 elements right?

Comment: yes. in the same time , when scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...];
values = values.splice(0,15); // remove first 15 items
values = values.concat([another 15 items]); // add next 15
```

And of course you can inline this:

```
values = values.splice(0,15).concat([x1...x2])
```

Comment: I tried your advice and I updated my answer , but doesn t work.

Comment: Are you sure you're using **splice** like in my answer? Looks like you're using **slice**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
numbers = numbers.slice(2).concat([11,12]);
console.log(numbers);

>> [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have array on scroll you can reinitialize your array:

```
var old= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 

scroll=[32, 232,23, 232, 23, 232, 23,238, 92, 120];

old=scroll;

console.log(old);
```

and if you ahve items one by one then you can use pattern:

if you have array on scroll you can reinitialize your array:

```
var old= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 

old.push(next_value);
old.shift()

console.log(old);
```